# Unable to consume rest service on jsp page using jquery ajax

Tags: eclipse, rest, spring-tool-suite, apache-tiles, jquery-ajaxq

I am using Spring Famework, JSP, Rest Service, JQuery Ajax & Apache Tiles.

My issue is, I am not able to consume rest API response on JSP page. The situation is when I use `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` I am happly able to consume rest api response on browser using URL but not able to access jsp pages since a Apache tiles have been configured for the same ,

```
<definition name="search" extends="template">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="Some value" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/search.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Pages can only be accessed if I use `<url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>` even if i am trying to access the two url patters together the tiles does not respond.

JQuery Ajax is like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert();
      $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url  : 'http://localhost:8080/b2b/itemCategory/readAll',
        success : function(itemCategory){
            console.log('success', itemCategory);}
    }) 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have not declared internalviewResolver (jstl view) along with tileviewresolver